# "Failed host look up: 'hostname' " appWrite on Android device in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, cross-platform, native, appwrite

Consider:

```
  static const String endPoint = 'http://192.168.18.22:8001/v1';
```

Here is my configuration for my endPoint project. "192.168.18.22:8001" is my IP address in my Android device:

Comment: Something *seems* to be missing at the end. Or not? Can you clarify by [changing your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76499718/edit)? (But *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question should appear as if it was written right now.)

Answer (score 0):

If you're running on an Android device, the localhost address is usually `10.0.0.2`.

Comment: the address  do not work for me, where you can find the localhost address in Android device

Comment: `  static const String endPoint = 'http://10.0.0.2:8001/v1';' here is my code after fixing

Comment: Did you try 'http://10.0.0.2:8001/v1' or 'http://10.0.0.2/v1'

Comment: I try both of them but it still do not work for me

Comment: here is my ip address in my computer " 192.168.18.23" and  here is in android device " 192.168.18.22"

Comment: Ok did you try this '192.168.18.23'

Comment: I do not know what anydesk address really means

Comment: I have tried all of that but all of  them did not work for me

Comment: https://anydesk.com/en

Comment: I would love to help you if you download it and share it with me

Comment: Sorry but i can not share the anyDesk

Comment: Ok,
Then you should try these:
To make sure the project you are running in your local is working, check the endpoint you are running, so when you access 'http://localhost:8001/v1' from your browser, make sure it is running then we can figure out where the problem is

Comment: Yeah , i am checking the problem , hope we can figure out where the problem is

Comment: Can you share your code ?

Comment: yes here is my link github prj : https://github.com/lethanhdathust/Twitter_prj2

Comment: I don't see any problem here.
What do you get when you access localhost via browser?

Comment: Yes there is a error, XML HttpRequest error  , i have try to run with " flutter run -d chrome --web-browser-flag "--disable-web-security" " but it still the same error

Comment: I don't understand, is your project not working on android?

Comment: yeah i tried the project in the android device but it not work , then i tried on the gg chorm but it still did not work

Comment: Can you navigate to this address from any browser on your computer? [link](http://localhost:8001/v1)

Comment: yes , I can , both chrome and edge

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74068727/getting-xmlhttprequest-error-when-using-flutter-web-but-works-in-mobile-app/74068805#74068805

Comment: "localhost" is confusing. The literal "localhost" is 127.0.0.1. Can you rephrase, please?

Comment: I have figured out the problem, instead of using setEndpoint() I have used setEndPointRealtime() so this made me the error.