# flutter web - download image from url, get Error: XMLHttpRequest error

Tags: flutter, xmlhttprequest, imagedownload

i want to download image from firebase storage using the url.

**here is my code**

```
Future<void> _download(String _url) async {
    print("START DOWNLOADDD");
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(_url));
    print("response done");

    final imageName = path.basename(_url);
    print(imageName);

    final appDir = await path_provider.getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    print(appDir);

    final localPath = await path.join(appDir.path, imageName);
    print(localPath);

    final imageFile = File(localPath);
    print("imageFile done");
    await imageFile.writeAsBytes(response.bodyBytes);
    print("download");

    listDownloadPath.add(await localPath);
    setState(() {});

    print(await "END DOWNLOADDDD");
```

}

it works in android, but when i try it on chrome it get error when get the response.

**here is the error**
[image: error]

is there any way that i can do to fix it? thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a problem that arises in part "http.get(Uri.parse(_url))"

I think it would be good to refer to this.

[Dart/Flutter: Http request raises XMLHttpRequest error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71157863/dart-flutter-http-request-raises-xmlhttprequest-error)

- Remove flutter_tools.stamp
  1- Go to flutter\bin\cache and remove a file named: flutter_tools.stamp
- Modify chrome.dart
  2- Go to flutter\packages\flutter_tools\lib\src\web and open the file chrome.dart.

3- Find '--disable-extensions'

4- Add '--disable-web-security'

=>
...

'--disable-extensions',

'--disable-web-security',

...

And use Uri.https('urlPath', 'callPath') instead of Uri.parse(url)