# Impossible to get raw information by using http request from flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, http

```
Future<void> fetchData() async {
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(
        'https://calendrier-des-brocantes.com/vide-greniers-brocante/manche-departement/30-07-2023/'));
```

**Error**

```
Error: XMLHttpRequest error.
    dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/core_patch.dart 942:28                get current
packages/http/src/browser_client.dart 81:22                                       <fn>
```

I was expecting raw informatin in order to analyze piece. of data

Comment: You need to add more info in order to have an answer

Comment: Possible duplicates: 1.) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60191683/xmlhttprequest-error-in-flutter-web-enabling-cors-aws-api-gateway 2.) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65630743/how-to-solve-flutter-web-api-cors-error-only-with-dart-code and 3.) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71157863/dart-flutter-http-request-raises-xmlhttprequest-error