# When I try to consume an API in flutter with HTTP I get Error: ClientException: XMLHttpRequest Error

Tags: flutter, dart, http

I have an app with flutter and I must consume an external API which when consuming it with the http library in flutter I get that error:

> Error: ClientException: XMLHttpRequest error

I thought it was the cors from the server I fixed it and the same error follows when testing the API in Postman I get 200 so I don't understand what happens.

```
final response = await http.post(
                                Uri.parse(
                                    'Here's the API link, I don't put it for security?idOrdenNumero=$idOrdenNumero&idPunto=$idPunto'),
                              );
```

In Postman it brings me 200 but in Flutter it doesn't and it comes out is the mistake.

Comment: It's going to be really hard for people to help you without more details.  Is that the entire error message?  Is there a stack trace?

Comment: Did you check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71157863/dart-flutter-http-request-raises-xmlhttprequest-error ?