# Flutter http.get request for DistanceMatrix Api not working

Tags: flutter, google-maps

I am trying to use the DistanceMatrixAPI to get a distance matrix that I will further work with. First I retrieve addresses and I geocode them with the Geocoding API (which works fine btw) and after that I use these coordinates to request a DistanceMatrix.

I always get an error for the distancematrix, even though when I copy the URI into Chrome I can see the correct json that I should be receiving. This means it isn't a problem concerning my API-key itself.

Can anyone help me?
[image: Error Showcase]

```
//This one works correctly:
Future<List<PointLatLng>> getInitialCoordinates(List<String> addresses) async {
  List<PointLatLng> geocodeList = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < addresses.length; i++) {
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(
        'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=${addresses[i]}&key=$key'));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      dynamic jsonLocation = jsonDecode(response.body);
      geocodeList.add(PointLatLng(
          jsonLocation['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat'],
          jsonLocation['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng']));
    } else {
      throw Exception('Laden der Addresse ${addresses[i]} fehlgeschlagen.');
    }
  }
  return geocodeList;

//This one always returns an error
Future<List<List<int>>> fetchDistanceMatrix(List<PointLatLng> coords) async {
  String fullAddressString = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < coords.length; i++) {
    if (i == 0) {
      fullAddressString = '${coords[i].latitude}%2C${coords[i].longitude}';
    } else {
      fullAddressString =
          "$fullAddressString|${coords[i].latitude}%2C${coords[i].longitude}";
    }
  }
  final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(
      'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?destinations=$fullAddressString&origins=$fullAddressString&key=$key'));
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    dynamic jsonLocation = jsonDecode(response.body);
    List<List<int>> distanceMatrix = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < coords.length; i++) {
      List<int> rowVector = [];
      for (var j = 0; j < coords.length; j++) {
        if (jsonLocation['rows'][i]['elements'][j]['status'] == 'OK') {
          rowVector
              .add(jsonLocation['rows'][i]['elements'][j]['duration']['value']);
        } else {
          throw Exception(
              'Laden der Addressen fehlgeschlagen: DistanceMatrixAPI kann die Koordinaten nicht finden.');
        }
      }
      distanceMatrix.add(rowVector);
    }
    return distanceMatrix;
  } else {
    throw Exception(
        'Laden der Addresse fehlgeschlagen. Mehrere Addressen sind falsch.');
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample request? Like the addresses you're trying to fetch. So that we can deduce if the issue comes from flutter itself or just the request as being invalid.

Comment: Like in the picture. Im requesting specifically distancematrix data from google maps. All other requests were working just fine.

Comment: Yeap, I totally understand this. And since the issue seems to be only on Distance Matrix, I would like to ask you a sample request like this one: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?destinations=$fullAddressString&origins=$fullAddressString&key=$key where you provide the origin and destination itself. You can leave out the API key since I have my own. This would help me reproduce and see if the issue is in the request or on the flutter implementation/library  itself.

Comment: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?destinations=48.856614,2.3522219|43.296482,5.36978|43.7101728,7.261953200000001|48.0793589,7.358511999999999|46.2043907,6.1431577&origins=48.856614,2.3522219|43.296482,5.36978|43.7101728,7.261953200000001|48.0793589,7.358511999999999|46.2043907,6.1431577&key=<YOUR_API_KEY>

Comment: It looks like the request seem to work fine outside the flutter environment. So this is more likely an issue with flutter or implementation.

Comment: After further looking into this, it looks like the error you are encountering is related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71157863/dart-flutter-http-request-raises-xmlhttprequest-error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dart/Flutter: Http request raises XMLHttpRequest error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71157863/dart-flutter-http-request-raises-xmlhttprequest-error)